# Java calculator gui number issue

Tags: java

When I run the code the gui pops up like it should but when I click on a button it gives this in the textfield box:

> javax.swing.JButton[,0,65,37x34,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@5066ef73,flags=41943328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=1,defaultCapable=tru

...when I only want the number to show up.

So my question is, how can I get this to go away or what is making my code do this?
The only thing that should be showing up is the number '1'

Here is my code:

```
 package Calc;


 public class Calculate extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  double firstNumber;
  double secondNumber;
  double finalResult;
  String operation;
  /**
   * Creates new form Calculate
   */
public Calculate() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    textDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Button1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Button12 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    textDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
    textDisplay.setMargin(null);
    textDisplay.setMaximumSize(null);
    textDisplay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            textDisplayActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button1.setText("1");
    Button1.setToolTipText("");
    Button1.setAutoscrolls(true);
    Button1.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    Button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button2.setText("2");
    Button2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button3.setText("3");
    Button3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button4.setText("4");
    Button4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button5.setText("5");
    Button5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button6.setText("6");
    Button6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button7.setText("7");
    Button7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button8.setText("8");
    Button8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button9.setText("9");
    Button9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button10.setText("c");
    Button10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button10ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button11.setText("0");
    Button11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button11ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Button12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    Button12.setText("+");
    Button12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Button12ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(textDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button3))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button5)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button6))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button7)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button8)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button9))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button10)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button11)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Button12)))
            .addGap(0, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(textDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Button1)
                .addComponent(Button2)
                .addComponent(Button3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Button4)
                .addComponent(Button5)
                .addComponent(Button6))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Button7)
                .addComponent(Button8)
                .addComponent(Button9))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Button10)
                .addComponent(Button11)
                .addComponent(Button12))
            .addContainerGap(88, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void Button5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button5;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button1;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);

}                                       

private void Button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button2;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button3;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
  String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button4;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button6;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
  String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button7;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button8;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button9;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                       

private void Button10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button10;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                        

private void Button11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button11;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                        

private void Button12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(textDisplay.getText());
  textDisplay.setText("");
  operation = "+";
  if(operation == "+")
  {
      finalResult = firstNumber + secondNumber;
      String answer = String.format("%.0f",finalResult);
      textDisplay.setText(answer);
  }
}                                        

private void textDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ textDisplay;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculate.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Calculate().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Button1;
private javax.swing.JButton Button10;
private javax.swing.JButton Button11;
private javax.swing.JButton Button12;
private javax.swing.JButton Button2;
private javax.swing.JButton Button3;
private javax.swing.JButton Button4;
private javax.swing.JButton Button5;
private javax.swing.JButton Button6;
private javax.swing.JButton Button7;
private javax.swing.JButton Button8;
private javax.swing.JButton Button9;
private javax.swing.JTextField textDisplay;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This code is your problem:

```
private void Button5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = textDisplay.getText()+ Button5;
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}
```

### Solution:

Change `textDisplay.getText()+ Button5` to `Button5.getText()`

```
private void Button5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   String inputNumber = Button5.getText();
    textDisplay.setText(inputNumber);
}
```

### Explanation:

`textDisplay.getText()+ Button5` really means `textDisplay.getText()+ Button5.toString()`

The `Button5.toString()` is what is generating all the junk you don't like to see.

### FYI:

`javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton)evt.getSource()` will give the button that trigged the event. This way you don't need a separate `ButtonXActionPerformed()` method for every button. (You can can register the same method for every button.)